# Create background process in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, backgroundworker

I have some data that can be shown only if its expiration date (it's set when data are creating) is greater than today and or its status is `Closed` (the status can be changed by user at any time). So when the data is expire its status should be automatically set to `Closed`.

In this case I want to create some **background task** that will check data once per day (this is the problem because usually hosters sets application pool idle-timeout for 20 minutes) and set status if data expired.

I read some articles of how to implement what I want. But, I don't know what is the best way to do this.

The main solutions are the following:

1. [Using `Cache` and its `CacheItemRemovedCallback` method](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/);
2. [Using `BackgroundWorker`](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/613/background-processes-in-asp-net-web-applications);
3. [Simple use of `Thread` in global.asax's `Application_Start` method](http://forums.asp.net/post/3224202.aspx);
4. [Using of `IRegisteredObject`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/).

So the question is: **What is the best way to implement background process in ASP.NET?**

P.S. I know that the better solution will be the Windows Service or Console Application that will be run in Scheduller. But I want make it in ASP.NET.

**EDIT:**

I use CodeFirst:

```
public class Theme
{
    //...
    [Required]
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; } }
    public Status? Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where (how/what) is the "expiring data" stored?

Comment: Can you just modify the query not to show unexpired data? To my knowledge, there is not a good way to run a background process inside of IIS. I always use a Windows service for scheduled work.

Comment: @Ryan, righht now I hide the dat awith query, but when I show this data to user(that can handle it), the user will see Status "Active" instead of close.

Comment: You can use a view model that would show the correct status if the record is expired.

Comment: @Ryan, oh, thanks, I think I will follow your suggestion, it will save at least one change request to database.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a task more suited to a scheduler. [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) would do what you want and would be pretty trivial to configure in this scenario:

```
public class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        // Find and update data here
    }
}

// define the job and tie it to our MyJobclass
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
    .WithIdentity("myJob")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run at midnight every day
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("myTrigger")
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.AtHourOfDay(0))
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever())
    .Build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

There are plenty of examples on the [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/index.html) pages for Quartz.